# Resource detailing Google Sheets API exceptions

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm using the google sheets API with python to upload data to a spreadsheet as my code collects it. I have encountered a few errors while testing that seemed to be due to a bad connection or an interruption as evidenced somewhat by the traceback and that re-running the same code without any changes works fine.

My question is where can I find a resource that details the types of errors I could encounter using this API, so that I can catch errors like those described above? I've searched through the documentation, but haven't been able to find one that describes the error type and how to catch it.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You may want to check the list of errors in [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors). Also based from this [link](https://www.hitchhq.com/googledrive/activities/handling-api-errors-drive-rest-api-google-developers-57597a9d8e2e411000b8e16b), there are two levels of error information, ***HTTP error codes and messages in the header*** and ***A JSON object in the response body with additional details that can help you determine how to handle the error***. Check the page which provides a reference of errors, with some guidance on how to handle them in your app.

Comment: Excellent! If you can post this as an answer I can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check the list of errors in [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors). Also based from this [link](https://www.hitchhq.com/googledrive/activities/handling-api-errors-drive-rest-api-google-developers-57597a9d8e2e411000b8e16b), there are two levels of error information, ***HTTP error codes and messages in the header*** and ***A JSON object in the response body with additional details that can help you determine how to handle the error***. Check the page which provides a reference of errors, with some guidance on how to handle them in your app.

Comment: The second page you linked to appears to be gone.