# Google Sheets API: Exception vs. Json in response body

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I am lost in error handling with Google Sheets API.

The [Sheets API reference page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest) does not provide any example of error handling.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48614865/resource-detailing-google-sheets-api-exceptions) points to a doc page saying:

> The Drive API returns two levels of error information:
>
> ```
> HTTP error codes and messages in the header.
> ```
>
> A JSON object in the response body with additional details that can help you determine how > to handle the error.
>
> Drive apps should catch and handle all errors that might be encountered when using the REST > API. This guide provides instructions on how to resolve specific API errors.

and then lists an example of json response for [404](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_404_error_file_not_found_fileid)

However when I run with a nonexistent spreadsheet_id the following code (it works fine on a correct spreadsheet_id):

```
request = service.spreadsheets().get(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
            ranges=ranges,
    )

response = request.execute()
```

I get an exception raised, rather than an error in json response:

```
  File ".../lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 915, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1Z2aQvO122lBxHyditlDT6KhSAqkiUeX8zqJ4ysIJHd?alt=json returned "Requested entity was not found.". Details: "Requested entity was not found.">
```

and it seems I can't even extract an error code without parsing a string.

So, the question is: how to correctly handle sheets api errors? I think I'd prefer to always get a json and catch an exception for truly technical errors such a bad connectivity etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You get an exception raised and the exception struct contains the json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- When an error occurs with Sheets API, you want to retrieve the error message from Sheets API as JSON data.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with python.
- You have already been able to use Sheets API using googleapis for python.

In this case, how about using try, except? The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError # <--- In this case, please add this.

try:

    # This is your script.
    request = service.spreadsheets().get(
        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
        ranges=ranges,
    )

    response = request.execute()
    print(response)

except HttpError as err:
    e = json.loads(err.content.decode("utf-8"))
    print(e)
```

- In this sample script, when `spreadsheet_id` is the valid value, the returned value can be seen with `print(response)`. When `spreadsheet_id` is the invalid value, the error message can be seen with `print(e)`. The sample value of `print(e)` is as follows.

  ```
    {'error': {'status': 'NOT_FOUND', 'message': 'Requested entity was not found.', 'code': 404, 'errors': [{'domain': 'global', 'message': 'Requested entity was not found.', 'reason': 'notFound'}]}}
  ```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that your `service` can be used for retrieving the values from Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [googleapis for python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)

Comment: Thanks for the example, it's now clear, that error codes and messages come with exception object. It was just confusing to see an exception where many other services just return an error code and  the message in the response itself. i.e. compare to `requests` library. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @Artem Trunov Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The "requested entity not found" error is normally caused by sending an invalid spreadsheetId.

You should check that the user who you have authenticated with actually has access to the sheet first. doing a file.list and searching for the mime type of sheets would be a good way to do that [try me](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22mimeType%3D%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.spreadsheet%27%22%7D&apix=true)

Comment: Yes, I deliberately tried an invalid id in order to see what the error response look like. My more specific question is why am I not getting a json response from google API with 404 code, but rather an http exception?  I think I just need a guidance on how to handle errors.

Comment: Well i didnt make the api but being that the id doesnt exist would infact make the following link 404 https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1Z2aQvO122lBxHyditlDT6KhSAqkiUeX8zqJ4ysIJHd  as it doesnt exist.  So it makes sense that it would throw a HTTP error.